# Generate divs on scroll bottom

Tags: javascript, html

I want to generate `<div>`s with javascript. When the page is scrolled down and when the last div appears on the screen, even a little bit, new 5 `<div>`s should generate beneath it. The last div on the page will have text written of divisible of 5 (e.g. 5,10,15,20...). If I have not been clear enough comment below.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(39, 40, 41);
    background-color: #00B9EF;
}

#navigation {
    background-color: #EFF3F4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: -1;
}

button {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #00B9EF;
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 5% 0% auto;
    float: right;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0% 15% 0% 15%;
    z-index: -1;
}

#box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 15% auto 15% auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FlexBox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="box">1</div>
        <div id="box">2</div>
        <div id="box">3</div>
        <div id="box">4</div>
        <div id="box">5</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var content = document.getElementById("content");
        var box_val = 5;
        window.onscroll = function(ev) {
            if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
                console.log("bottom");
                var sentence = "";
                for (var x=1;x<=5;x++) {
                    sentence += "<div id='box'>" + (box_val + x) + "</div>";
                }
                box_val += 5;
                content.innerHTML += sentence;
                console.log("1: ", (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY), "\n2: ", document.body.scrollHeight);
            } else {
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but I ran the snippet and it keeps generating divs. Also after 10.

Comment: If no one awnsers this by tomorrow I'll work out a solution. I'm not at my work pc. But you may want to look at doing it with jquery. And looking at jquery Inviewport

Comment: No clue where is your problem. I'm at div 100 and still going.

Comment: Question has been edited above

Comment: I guess instead of using condition like height and bottom you should check if last element is visible using offset of that Element so it fixes your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change `id="box"` to `class="box"` and then get last element with `class="box"` in `content`. But it works now.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(39, 40, 41);
    background-color: #00B9EF;
}

#navigation {
    background-color: #EFF3F4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: -1;
}

button {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #00B9EF;
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 5% 0% auto;
    float: right;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0% 15% 0% 15%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 15% auto 15% auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FlexBox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navigation">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="box">1</div>
        <div class="box">2</div>
        <div class="box">3</div>
        <div class="box">4</div>
        <div class="box">5</div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var content = document.getElementById("content");
        var box_val = 5;
        const scrollOffset = 0; // change to higher value if you want to add new divs when scroll is on last box + scrollOffset
        window.onscroll = function(ev) {
            let box = content.querySelectorAll(".box:last-child")[0]; // get last box
            if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= box.offsetTop + scrollOffset) { // check if scrolled past last box
                var sentence = "";
                for (var x=1;x<=5;x++) {
                    sentence += "<div class='box'>" + (box_val + x) + "</div>";
                }
                box_val += 5;
                content.innerHTML += sentence;
            } else {
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, this `offsetTop` method will help me with future things too I think, thanks